# How do I auto increment a cell by plus 1 on a certain date?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently working on a budget sheet and I need to know how many payments are left on my loan. I need to increment my number of payments cell by 1 the 10th of every month.

Can I do it within Google Sheets or do I need to add a script?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a script but given a start date (here A1) a formula might work:

```
 =month(today())-month(A1)+if(day(today())>10,1,0)
```

possibly with another IF function to allow for change of year.